# Retrofit network response returning null in Rxjava2

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2

***This is the code and my response is returning null, I'm using RXjav2 observable and live data. I want to get current, my location is Lagos and it is queried in the retrofit interface. I'm using the weather stack API

2020-02-29 15:49:10.309 17988-17988/com.example.weatherapp D/networks: null

---

```
  data class Weather (
      @SerializedName("name")
      val location: String,
      @SerializedName("weather_descriptions")
      val description: List<String>,
      @SerializedName("temperature")
      val temperature: Long,
      @SerializedName("wind_speed")
      val windSpeed: Long,
      @SerializedName("wind_dir")
      val windDir: String,
      @SerializedName("precip")
      val precipitation: Long,
      @SerializedName("humidity")
      val humidity: Long,
      @SerializedName("visibility")
      val visibility: Long,
      @SerializedName("weather_icons")
      val icon: List<String>
  ): Parcelable



  data class Request(
      @SerializedName("language")
      val language: String,
      @SerializedName("query")
      val query: String,
      @SerializedName("type")
      val type: String,
      @SerializedName("unit")
      val unit: String
  ) 



data class Location(
      @SerializedName("country")
      val country: String,
      @SerializedName("lat")
      val lat: String,
      @SerializedName("localtime")
      val localtime: String,
      @SerializedName("localtime_epoch")
      val localtime_epoch: Int,
      @SerializedName("lon")
      val lon: String,
      @SerializedName("name")
      val name: String,
      @SerializedName("region")
      val region: String,
      @SerializedName("timezone_id")
      val timezone_id: String,
      @SerializedName("utc_offset")
      val utc_offset: String
  )
```

**Response data class**

```
 data class WeatherResponse(
    @SerializedName("current")
    val current: Weather,
    @SerializedName("location")
    val location: Location,
    @SerializedName("request")
    val request: Request
)
```

**Network Interface**

```
   interface ApixuApi {
       @GET("current///")
       fun getWeather(@Query("access_key") api: String = Util.API_KEY,
                          @Query("query") location: String = "Lagos"): Observable<WeatherResponse>
```

**Datasource Interface**

```
interface DataSource {

    fun getWeather(): LiveData<WeatherResponse>

    fun refreshWeather()

    fun saveWeather(weather: Weather)

    fun clearWeather()

}
```

```
 package com.example.weatherapp.dataSource

 import android.util.Log
 import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
 import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
 import com.example.weatherapp.model.Weather
 import com.example.weatherapp.model.WeatherResponse
 import com.example.weatherapp.network.ApixuApi
 import com.example.weatherapp.util.NetworkState
 import io.reactivex.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers
 import io.reactivex.disposables.CompositeDisposable
 import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers

 class RemoteDataSource(private val api: ApixuApi, private val compositeDisposable: CompositeDisposable) : DataSource {

     private val _networkState = MutableLiveData<NetworkState>()
     val networkState: LiveData<NetworkState>
     get() = _networkState

     private val _apiResponse = MutableLiveData<WeatherResponse>()
     val apiResponse
     get() = _apiResponse

     override fun getWeather(): LiveData<WeatherResponse> {
         _networkState.postValue(NetworkState.LOADING)

         var data:Weather? = null

         try {
             compositeDisposable.add(
                 api.getWeather()
                     .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                     .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                     .subscribe(
                         {
                         //  data = _apiResponse.value.current
                           // data =  it
                            //data =  _apiResponse.value!!.current
                             data = _apiResponse.value!!.current
                             Log.d("remotedd", _apiResponse.value!!.current.toString())
                             _networkState.postValue(NetworkState.LOADED)
                         },
                         {
                             _networkState.postValue(NetworkState.ERROR)
                             Log.d("networks", it.message.toString())
                         }
                     )
             )

         }catch (e: Exception){
             Log.d("networks", e.message.toString())
         }
         return apiResponse
     }

     override fun refreshWeather() {
         _apiResponse.value = getWeather().value

     }

     override fun saveWeather(weather: Weather) {
         TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
     }

     override fun clearWeather() {
         TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
     }


 }
```

**I need help on how to figure this out, my response is null**

Comment: Is there any logs?

Comment: btw this is wrong: `.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` and should be `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())`

Comment: Yes, the app didn't crash. but my log gave this 2020-02-29 15:55:16.993 19720-19720/com.example.weatherapp D/networks: null. Thanks for the correction

Comment: @MaryJane the order of `observeOn` and `subscribeOn` doesn't matter.

Comment: @WaqarUlHaq I know. I'm just saying it's better to write it that way

Comment: Instead of printing the exception message, could you please print the exception stack trace and update your question with it. I think it's easier from there.